# Android: how to permanently & completely NOT show default soft keyboard for an EditText?

Tags: java, android

I have three EditText boxes in an activity, for two of which normal input methods (hard keys, default soft keyboard) are ok. But for one of the EditText boxes I want to send soft input only from a custom keyboard view. So in effect I want the default soft keyboard never to be shown for this EditText. I've tried adding onTouchListeners and onFocusChange listeners for the EditText with partial success like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.requestFocus();
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
    return true;
}

public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive(v)) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0,0);
    }
}
```

But I have not achieved a definitive solution because

1)the default soft keyboard always briefly flashes visible before the listener hides it

2)on some occasions, such as moving focus to the EditText with hard keyboard arrow keys sometimes sets the default soft keyboard visible

and so on.

So I would love to find a simple way to tell Android never to show the default soft keyboard for this specific EditText. I would not like to extend EditText and start to override stuff, since the EditText functionality is perfect for me - I just want the default soft keyboard not to be shown.

I've spent days now trying to figure this out. Some topics (including some here) found via google have half-way attempts at this problem, but so far I haven't found a single totally functional solution.

EDIT:

I'm really starting to get annoyed. I decided I could try not to use EditText but whatever other view that will get the job done. It turns out it is freakin hard to get rid of that soft keyboard. It even shows up when I use the hard keys to move focus from an EditText to a Button! Why on earth should the soft keyboard be shown on every freakin View that happens to have focus? Even when I explicitly say inputType="none"? How do I turn that ***** soft keyboard OFF? Below is the xml for the Button - let's use that as an example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/OkButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:paddingRight="5mm"
    android:paddingLeft="5mm"
    android:layout_below="@id/Volume"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

EDIT2:

I have how achieved a solution that seems to work. First I get a hold of the InputMethodManager:

```
this.imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

and the I set OnClickListener, OnTouchListener and OnFocusChange listener all call the following method when I want the EditText to be focused and my custom KeyboardView visible, while hiding the default soft input:

```
private boolean makeActive(View v) {
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    EditText e = (EditText) v;
    int iType = e.getInputType();
    e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    e.requestFocus();
    showKb();
    e.setInputType(iType);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @zenperttu: "But for one of the EditText boxes I want to send soft input only from a custom keyboard view." -- Then do not make it an `EditText`. Regardless of your IME issues, your users will give you one-star ratings on the Market, indicating that your app is broken, if you make something look like an `EditText` yet not behave as an `EditText` does (e.g., allow the user to do silly little things like editing text).

Comment: @CommonsWare: I do not wish to prevent user entering/editing text in the EditText. I accept hard keys and will show a custom keyboard view for the EditText that controls the characters user can input, much like when you set the input type for an EditText so that for example when numeric input is expected, letters will not be shown on the soft keyboard. Now there just is no ready-made Android input type and corresponding keyboard layout available. To be more specific, my custom keyboard layout will only show some of the symbols specified in the SI metric system, including greek characters.

Comment: @CommonsWare: if you can suggest an alternative to EditText I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @zenperttu: You claim to support "hard keys", yet you also say that the only valid input is "some of the symbols specified in the SI metric system, including greek [sic] characters". Few physical keyboards have any such characters, so those two claims do not match, IMHO. Hence, I have no idea what data you are trying to collect, or why. As a result, I have no way to "suggest an alternative". All I am saying is that if you have an `EditText`, and the behavior is not *at least* 90% of what an `EditText` is supposed to be, expect complaints.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have set up an InputFilter that will transform the necessary hard keys into corresponding symbols, for example hard keyboard keystroke "u" will be replaced by greek small letter "mu". Incompatible characters from hard keyboard will be filtered out - and maybe the app will notify the user not to input stuff that does not make sense. A valid input will be the following units "l (liter), g (gram), mol (mole)" and the prefixes for fractions. (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-SI_units_accepted_for_use_with_SI).

Comment: @zenperttu: If that is it, why are you bothering with a dedicated keyboard and breaking the existing IME? Just use the same filtering mechanism you are using for the hardware keyboard. People who use, say, Swype, will be confused (and possibly irritated) when they try to use your `EditText` and discover that their chosen keyboard has somehow been disabled. Personally, I think the answer is that apps should be able to define their own IMEs, and users should be able to opt into those IMEs when in those apps, but that's not possible today.

Comment: @zenperttu: To provide simpler input while still not breaking the user's choice of IME, offer a button to the side of the `EditText` that pops up a toolbar to insert special characters at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Some people suggested that the following might work on older versions of Android, but the behaviour is unexpected.

```
edittextPlay.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
       .hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBox.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

where SearchBox is your textbox or better yet instead of SearchBox get your current displayed window.

Or try:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getBaseContext()
     .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

where context is `getApplicationContext();`

Comment: I have tried calling those from my Activity's onCreate method. The first suggestion does not seem to have an effect and the latter causes for some reason my app to crash. Maybe I really need to use something else than an EditText - but I really think this would not be a very nice solution as all other user input goes to EditText boxes. Thanks for the effort in any case!

Comment: Edit: the program crashing was due to another bug, but calling     imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); does not seem to have effect either. Am I calling it from the wrong place when I call it from my Activity's onCreate()?