# Suppress Soft Input (hide keyboard) for Edittext view

Tags: android, android-input-method

I'm trying to make a simple calculator and to do so, I want to, and exit view that the user can move the courser within but can only input based off of the buttons I've included.

When I press on the Edittext view, however, the keyboard pops up and I can't figure out how to suppress it - I've tried both `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` and `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"` in the manifest and also

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//Hide keyboard
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

In Java but none of them work

Comment: Sounds like this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880144/android-how-to-permanently-completely-not-show-default-soft-keyboard-for-an-e?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help but I've just found a solution

XML:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/InputLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/Sixth_Up"
        android:onClick="hideKeyboard">

    </EditText>
```

Java:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editInput.getWindowToken(),0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that view is in focus and then hide the keyboard.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```